# Unity3D - portable HTTP client

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, httpclient, portability

I'm new to Unity3D and i want to write simple HTTP client to connect to my server, send custom data and return with result.

I could write something using C# sockets (.NET classes), but i'm not sure how portable will this be. Can i count on that C# scripts that will work on Windows (using sockets etc.) will also work on other platforms (Linux, web, Android, iOS, windows phone)? Or only core basic functionality is supported and other .NET features are not portable (won't work on other than Windows platform)?

Comment: If you need portability, I'd opt either for mono libraries or native unity. Obviously MS windows libraries won't work on iOS etc.

Answer (score 1):

Any library that unity c# scripts can access will be cross platform. There are only a few things that mono doesn't support, from memory these will all be stuff related to the registry or other windows specific features.

You should worry about cross platform issues when dealing with user libraries, especially any that use native code. Sockets are in either mscorlib or the System library, both of which will be available in all mono platforms.

Unity uses mono internally, even on windows. So any issues related to differences between .net framework and mono should come up straight away.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas how to go in "http client" direction? I'm kinda new to .NET and C#. WWW class from Unity3D seems not-so-high with options, but sockets on the other hand are very low-level stuff. Crossplatform is a must at this point. Any C# (or .NET) classes that might come in handy and should be portable to other OSs?

Comment: Does unity have the System.Net.Http library? They have a HTTPClient which should have everything you need.